# How to sort factors

Tags: java

I'm very new to this and I'm stuck with doing my assignment so can anyone please help. I'm having trouble sorting the output. here is the code.

```
            import java.util.Scanner;

            public class CJPSA5 {
                public static void main(String args[]){
                    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
                    int num;
                    int m;
                    int r;
                    System.out.print("Please Enter your Number: ");
                    num = in.nextInt();

                    if (num <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("Not Accepted!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The Factor of "+ num + " " + "are:"); 
                        for (m = 1; m <= num; m++) {
                            if (num % m == 0) {
                                System.out.print(m + "\t");
                                System.out.print(j + "\t");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank You!");
    }
}
```

The expected output is like this.

```
Please Enter your Number: 24
The Factor of 24 are:
1   -1   2   -2   3   -3   4   -4   6   -6   8   -8   12  -12  24  -24
```

Now what i wanted to be the output is to be sorted like

```
1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24 -1 -2 -3 -4 -6 -8 -12 -24
```

I really hope someone could help me and sorry for my wrong grammar.

Comment: The code in your question is not the code you are using. Why not?

Comment: Your code will not compile

Comment: You are printing out a j variable but that is nowhere in your code. Instead of printing, trying saving the answers to an ArrayList and then sorting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code has a lot of compilation errors.

No need to sort the array. Only store the positive factors in the array.

Your array will be sorted by itself the way you are running the loop. Just loop through the array print negative of each number the second time around to print the negative factors.

For example:
input: `14`

Array has `1 2 7 14` and also these values have been printed by now.

Then loop through it and print: `-1 -2 -7 -14`

Comment: did what you said.. but I'm having index out of bounds Exception

Comment: How are you looping the array?

Comment: If you have the solution, please mark the appropriate answer as the solution by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values in an array or an arraylist in java. and the use a sorting method for that.

You can do it as Tapan Anand suggested as well without the use of sorting.

Comment: There is no need to sort.

Answer (score 1):

First collect your solutions in a list:

At the top:

```
List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then in the loop:

```
if (num % m == 0)
    factors.add(m);
```

Then after the loop:

```
Collections.sort(factors);
```

Then to print:

```
for (int factor : factors) {
    System.out.println(factor + "\t"); /// or whatever
```